# Password-less SSH login on Raspbain Wheezy

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, debian, public-key-encryption, raspbian

On Ubuntu machines I just add this line in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
ssh-rsa XXXsdfsdfqw3eqwesdsdfasdfasdfadfrsdfsdfsdf=
```

I did the same on Raspberry PI running Raspbian Wheezy. But when I try to do password-less login using my private key in Putty, I get the following error:

```
Using username "pi".
Server refused our key
pi@192.168.0.5's password:
```

How do I get it to work with my existing key?

Comment: make sure you have correct access rights both on the directory and on the file. What does `ls -ld ~/.ssh` and `ls -ld ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on you raspberry return?

Comment: Yes. It was permission related issue. Did sudo chown pi:pi .ssh and sudo chown pi:pi .ssh/autherized_keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was permission related issue. 
Did

`sudo chown pi:pi .ssh`

and

`sudo chown pi:pi .ssh/autherized_keys`

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=79932&p=568968

Answer (score 2):

There is fastest and effective way to copy your public key to a remote machine's is with [ssh-copy-id](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id)

```
ssh-copy-id pi@192.168.0.5
```

If you edit *authorized_keys* by hand ensure that *authorized_keys* and *.ssh* folder has the correct permissions :

```
chown -Rv -- pi:pi ~/.ssh/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Thanks, since I have not tried this, I ticked what I tried and worked. But ssh-copy-id looks like a better way to do it.

Comment: I prefer `ssh-copy-id` instead of editing `authorized_keys` - much easier/fast and avoids mistakes with permissions or access problems.